# NETSUITE - Error INVALID_KEY_OR_REF when I try to enter the Unit of Measure when creating a sales Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, unit-type, suiteql

Netsuite gives me an error when I try to enter the Unit of Measure when creating a sales order from SuiteScript with a Client Script.

PART OF CODE:

```
so.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId:'item',
      fieldId:'units',
      value:'Each', //resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'units'}), 
      ignoreFieldChange: true,
      forceSyncSourcing: true
});
```

Error message:

[image: ERROR MESSAGE IMAGE]

I have tried with Name, Plural Name, etc.

I need to know how I should load this field, to possibly bring it with SuiteQL from Units Type records, but I can't get it to accept anything by testing.

can someone please help me?

Comment: When calling `setCurrentSublistValue` you should use the `internalid`, which corresponds to `Each`, as `value`.

Comment: I already tried and neither. tnx